# Unable to remove GIMP no matter what

Tags: uninstall, gimp, purge

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
GIMP 2.10.34

Tried to remove GIMP and it was still there. So I restarted OS and it's still there. DId the following again and - it's still there:

Command history:

```
$ rm ~/.gimp
rm: cannot remove '/home/ptosis/.gimp': No such file or directory
$ sudo apt-get autoremove gimp
[sudo] password for ptosis: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gimp' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
$ sudo snap remove gimp
snap "gimp" is not installed
$ sudo apt-get remove gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gimp' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ sudo apt-get purge gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'gimp' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

All I wanted to do was install G'mic which I can't. So I figure I remove-purge-clean  - I've tried everything and GIMP is still there. Still doesn't have  the G-mic add-on.  Still says Python-fu and Script-fu only.
The program is still there - still working.

[image: Still there]

Comment: `snap remove gimp`? `flatpak remove gimp`?

Comment: How you installed `gimp` (ie. AppImage, FlatPak, Snap, Deb, from source etc) will determine the command used to remove it.  Ask the owner of the system for details as to how it was installed (*or review logs etc*), as we're limited to details provided in the question.

Comment: Well, I'm just going to stay with the GIMP I have. Just found out I can do G'mic online @ https://gmicol.greyc.fr/   I did the snap remove gimp but not the flatpak remove gimp.   But everything fine now since found G'Mic online. That was the original intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed the flatpak version of Gimp. So the command to uninstall would be

```
flatpak uninstall org.gimp.GIMP
```

However, it appears that [GMIC also has a flatpak version](https://gmic.eu/download.html) that installs the Gimp plugin for the flatpak'ed Gimp:

```
flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP.Plugin.GMic
```

Alternatively if you use GMIC outside of Gimp anyway, you can installs its command line version....

Comment: Thank you very much.  You solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows most GIMP files at `.var/app/`. Looks a lot like Flatpak.

Neither apt nor snapd know anything about Flatpak (nor each other), so it's understandable that they could not remove your Flatpak.

Gentle reminder that it's the human's job to keep track of what was installed and by which method for each. The system will not remember for you.